Expo Go crashes since SDK 52
Since my expo go on IOS was updated to SDK 52,
I managed to update EXPO on my project to make it work.
also, I updated all my dependencies.
for some reason, when I click on a clickable element in the app, any of them, the app just crashes.
Tried to reinstall, restart the phone, and more....
Do you guys have any idea what can cause that?

may be you need to update react too,
